# How to pass a parameter to a csv file that is contains javascripts and also parameterised in my jmeter script

Tags: performance, csv, jmeter, nested, parameter-passing

i have a en-coded format javascript in a csv file that is used by jmeter to run my WEB PAGE TEST. how can i send a parameters to that csv file that is already serves as parameter for my jmeter

Answer (score 0):

If the data from CSV file contains JMeter Functions or Variables and you want to resolve their values in the runtime you need to use [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) for this.

Also regarding JavaScript: using it is some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). Moreover, [JavaScript engine was removed in JDK 15](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8236933?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%253Aall-tabpan) so your tests will be not future proof.

More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, i have one problem, my data in the CSV file is in encoded formate, so, jmeter variable with in the this csv file is lost during the run time. so i am not able to replace the data from other CSV file.

Comment: setUserAgent%20Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Linux%3B%20Android%206.0.1%3B%20Nexus%205X%20Build%2FMMB29P)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F102.0.5005.115%20Mobile%20Safari%2F537.36%20WPT_Soasta%0AsetCookie%09https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jcpenney.com%09%20%20%20DP-Cloud-Origin%3D%24%7B__eval(%24%7Benvcloud%7D)%7D%0AsetCookie%09https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jcpenney.com%09%20%20%20SVCVER%3Dlatest%0AsetCookie%09https%3A%2F%2F.jcpenney.com%09DPCPT%3D%7CCP1N%7CCP2N%7CCP3N%7CCP4Y%7CCP5Y%0AaddHeader%09x-jcpcloud-origin%3A%20%24%7B__eval(%24%7Benvcloud%7D)%7D%0AsetEventName%09